# Has anyone implemented an android plugin for unity using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have written an android app using openCV and native code, but when I try to extract the libraries for Unity it crashes when it loads the OpenCV libs.

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
         Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), not working.");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "  OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), working.");
    }        
//This doesn't work either
//OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this and load OpenCV libs? Or should I create another interface for Unity and load the .jar without extending UnityPlayerActivity?

Answer (score 2):

The time you will spend implementing and converting this to a plugin is not worth it. Use already made [plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088) from the Asset store. Not free but it is worth it as it supports other platforms as well.